# Listagem de posts de uma Taxonomy - Wordpress PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

[WORDPRESS] Help

Boa tarde, galera, algum especialista em WP na área? Eu estou começando a me aventurar no WP e algo não está dando muito certo. Tenho um PostType chamado imóveis, aonde na página empreendimentos eu listo todos os imóveis e também para este PostType eu tenho uma taxonomy personalizada (status_imoveis). Na página empreendimento eu listo todos os imóveis, mas para cada status eu queria listar os imóveis daquele status, porém, eu já tentei de tudo para criar a página desta taxonomy personalizada mas nada dá certo, já tentei taxonomy-imoveis.php, já tentei taxonomy-status_imoveis.php, enfim, sempre dá página 404.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Agradeço desde já.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Se for erro 404, tenta gerar um novo htaccess, indo em Configurações > Links Permanentes e sem fazer qualquer alteração clicar em salvar (que ele gera um novo htaccess e atualiza todos os rewrites).